# How to get the first and last value that match condition in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in this format:

[image]

I would like to get the first and last date (column A) that hasn't been invoiced (column E) so I can later concatenate: `="Invoice for items between " & FIRST_DATE & " and " & LAST_DATE`

I've tried using VLOOKUP but it appears that "" isn't interpreted as an empty match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think this would work.

```
=TEXT(MIN(FILTER(1*LEFT(A2:A;10);A2:A<>"";E2:E=""));"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

and

```
=TEXT(MAX(FILTER(1*LEFT(A2:A;10);A2:A<>"";E2:E=""));"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Your timestamps are coming from a system other than GoogleSheets.  They need to be "forced" into numbers before they can be MIN()'d and MAX()'d.  That's what 1* LEFT(... , 10) does.

Then they need to get turned *back* into text before they're concatenated in a text string like your plan.  That's what TEXT(... ,"yyyy-mm-dd") does.

Comment: I've seen other folks do the same with `+0` to force a number - Sheets also has a function for this, `VALUE()`. For example

```=TEXT(MAX(FILTER(VALUE(LEFT(A2:A;10));A2:A<>"";E2:E=""));"yyyy-mm-dd")```